# opencart .htaccess mod_rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I am using mode rewrite on an open cart system for seo url-s, it's working great according to the links. BUT I have a php code in the header:

```
<?php
$request = new Request();
if ( !isset($request->get['route']) ||  $request->get['route']=='common/home' ) { ?>
<div class="center-main">
<?php }else {?>
<div class="center-mainbg">
```

so if its not common/home, the div should inject `<div class="center-mainbg">`
and this rule doesent seams to work when mode rewrite is on, it is keeping the 
`<div class="center-main">` rule...

The htaccess rule for mod_rewrite looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i see it you just need to change the route variable name to:

```
if ( !isset($request->get['_route_']) ||  $request->get['_route_']=='common/home' ) { ?>
```

because in the Redirect rule the name of route is between underscores.

Comment: Perfect, working great:) thanks... can you describe why you need to add those? O.o

Comment: you need them because of this:
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]